# How do I mock a locally created object?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

This is my class.

```
class Test {
    public void print(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        restTemplate.getForObject("url", String.class);
    }
}
```

to test this class, I want to mock "RestTemplate". Is there any way to do this without changing the code.

Comment: You can't. That's why Spring is, at its core, a dependency injection framework. You pass the dependencies to mock as argument to the component constructor (or setters).

Comment: dependency injection

Comment: Well, you _can_ do this with [Powermock (MockConstructor)](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor), but you really _shouldn't_ if you can change the source code to accept injected dependencies instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *can't* be done without changing the code, at least not in an elegant way.

You create a new instance of `RestTemplate` each time you enter the `print()` method, so there's no way to pass in a mock.

Slightly change the method to use RestTemplate as a parameter. At runtime this will be an actual instance of RestTemplate, but when unit testing the method it's able to accept a mock.

```
class Test {
    public void print(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        restTemplate.getForObject("url", String.class);
    }
}

class TestTest {

    private final Test instance = new Test();

    @Test
    public testPrint() {
        RestTemplate restTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);

        instance.print(restTemplateMock);

        // TODO: verify method calls on the mock
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you [can](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) mock constructors with bytecode manipulation, but whether you should, that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a injected instance of the `RestTemplate` for your tests.

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

In the test setup, you can mock the `restTemplate`'s behavior as wanted.

Comment: Throwing spring at a problem just to make a class testable is a bit overshooting...